How do I get LaTex to run on VSCode (Windows 10)
I have previously used LaTex in limited extend in Microsoft Word but since I started working on some personal projects using VSCode, I decided to start using Latex to write my papers there too.
Sadly I cannot seem to run it, at least not completely, and at the same time I'm having troubles understanding all the documentation.
What ive done so far is add LaTex and LaTex Workshop on my VSCode, I haven't gone through the installation process in their respective documentations, as I have trouble understanding what exactly am I supposted to install.
Regardless, I tried creating a .tex file, and all seemed to work well until I attempted to create a matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}[
    Z\cdot\omega_Y-Y\cdot\omega_Z &
     X\cdot\omega_Z-Z\cdot\omega_X &
     X\cdot\omega_X-X\cdot\omega_Y]
\end{bmatrix}

This code creates an error when compiling, only if I use "matrix" instead of "bmatrix" and dont use a "&" does it not crash. I also can't seem to create a new row in the matrix.
I very much apologize if this can all be resolved reading documentation carefully, however I am quite overwhelmed by the amount of information and frankly quite confused as though what to do.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Welcome! What you show is not complete. Start at learnlatex.org or some similar place.

You need to have a TeX installation on your machine as well. Did you install MikTeX or TeXLive? Also, a proper TeX file should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document} if you want to compile it with PDFLaTeX or the like.

Why do you think that \begin{bmatrix}[ ... ] \end{bmatrix} is the correct syntax for a matrix?

As it stands, it is difficult to help you. You might want to explain what kind of error you get. TeX creates a .log file which you can check after compilation. If an error is thrown, you can look it up there. Almost always, the first error you see is the best hint to the relevant problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Beside the fact that you need to install LaTeX https://miktex.org, I also recommend using TeXStudio https://texstudio.org. It's much easier to use, especially if you're relatively new to LaTeX.

Thanks everyone, ! I was able to sort out the problem, which was me incorrectly installing MikTex.

First install MikTeX or TeXLive and be sure that you are able of compile a document without  VSCode (from the console ot from some latex editor as Texworks (already installed with Miktext). Then, if VSCode still does not work, reinstall the plugins.
